# Python: Which pattern to use to add functionality to django models

Tags: python, django, design-patterns, django-models

I have several models in my **Django** project. Most of these models are quite simple, but some of they are the entry point to complex data structures.

For example, `Reservation` model has several detail models through foreign key relationships (`ReservationHotel`, `ReservationTransfer`, `ReservationTour`, `ReservationRountrip`, `ReservationService`), and each one of these details has foreign relationship with product models (`Hotel`, `Transfer`, `Tour`, `Roundtrip`, `Services`).

I know a good practice is to keep models isolated from other models, so they must not know the detail about them. Due to this, I implement controllers to manage complex data structures like the one described before.

I want these controller to implement **design patterns**, and I believe the proper one for `Reservations` should be the *Proxy* pattern, based in its description in wikipedia:

> What problems can the Proxy design pattern solve?
>
> The access to an
>   object should be controlled .
>
> Additional functionality should be
>   provided when accessing an object.
>
> When accessing sensitive objects,
>   for example, it should be possible to check that clients have the
>   needed access rights.
>
> What solution does the Proxy design pattern describe?
>
> Define a
>   separate Proxy object that can be used as substitute for another object (Subject) and
>
> implements additional functionality to control the access to this subject.

In my case, I want to create a *proxy* for model `Reservation` that would handle also the information for its foreign references, so `Reservation` model would keep its encapsulation but the proxy would manage all the information related to a **Reservartion** instance.

Is that a proper use of a *Proxy* pattern?

Comment: You should not isolate tables in a relational data base from other tables. You should in fact create foreign key which establish the correct relationships between them. Actually, I don't think any design patterns are applicable for relational data model design.

Comment: I think I didn't make myself clear enough (sorry about that, language limitations). Of courser my models relationships are defined through foreign keys. What I want is the main model (`Reservation`) to create some entries in related models automatically (for example). Encapsulation of models implies that you should not trigger the creation of instances in other models. That is the reason why I am thinking of creating controllers to deal with these duties.

Comment: It is not clear from you comment what you mean by _"main model"_ and what you mean by _"model"_. For me, there is only one _model_. It defines all of the tables in the data base. Do you by _"model"_ mean one table? Encapsulation does not apply to data base model. What do you mean by _"trigger the creation of instances in other models"_? Please, show some code that you have, otherwise this answer is unclear and cannot be answered. I suggest also reading https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Sorry, by *model* I mean a class that derives from class `model` , and by *main model* I mean a class that derives from class `model` that has several other models (classes that derive from class `model`) that reference such main model through foreign keys.

Comment: In other words, a _"model"_ is a data base table. If you want to learn how to best organize data base tables, forget about design patterns and for a moment forget about Django and Python as well. Django and Python are just providing an interface with the data base. If you want to design the date model, learn how to do that on the SQL level. You will then understand why design patterns do not apply.

Comment: Well, I think my database tables are already well designed and implemented, what I am asking now is what would be the best way to handle them from the application using Design Patterns. I don't think that a Django model should take the responsibility of creating records in other models.

Comment: so I want to know if **proxy** pattern would be the right one for that. For example, when a new **Hotel** is created, several new records have to be created in model **Product** automatically with data from the new **Hotel** record. I don't think the class `Hotel`, that represents a database table, should handle this because model should only take care of their own businesses. I am not sure if I should use a **Proxy** or a **Facade** for this instance.